# How to convert AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint in spring 2 to spring 4

Tags: java, xml, spring, authentication, filter

Good day,

Before this, I have a old project working on Spring security core 2.0.7. When user is not log in, and I simply browse the application URL in browser, it will automatic link to login.html page. (Let say I browse the view user mode page url)

In the spring security xml, I have the following code:

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/403_system.jsp" session-fixation-protection="newSession"
            entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/session_expired.jsp" filters="none"/>
        <!-- some other intercept-url here ...-->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/common/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/common2/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

        <security:http-basic/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
            class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html" />
        <property name="forceHttps" value="${url.forceHttps}" />
        <property name="serverSideRedirect" value="${url.serverSideRedirect}" />
    </bean>
```

I believe that it is because of the `authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint`, so when it found that the if there is no Authentication, then it will direct it to `/login.html`.

In new project, we change to use spring security 4.2.0, and the configuration totally change, the following is part of the security config in java code:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // disable csrf
    http
        // UrlAuthorizationConfigurer
        .apply(new UrlAuthorizationConfigurer<>(getApplicationContext())).getRegistry()
        .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager()).antMatchers("/myapps/**")
        .access("IS_AUTHORISED_SERVICE").and()

        .csrf().disable()
        // same frame
        .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()


        .authorizeRequests()

        // permit all
        .antMatchers("/session_expired.jsp", "/system_error.jsp", "/images/**", "/scripts/**",
            "/styles/**", "/public/**", "/admin/**", "/login*", "/logout*", "/resources/**")
        .permitAll()
        // the rest authenticate
        .anyRequest().authenticated()


        // require login
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").successHandler(successHandler())
        .failureHandler(failureHandler()).loginProcessingUrl("/j_security_check").permitAll().and()
        .addFilterAfter(securityContextDetailsFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(logoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
  }
```

I believe I need to do something in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` class, but I cant really know how to code it. I try to google around, but didnt get the thing I want, I believe that I didnt google it correctly.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

The class

`org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint`

has been renamed to

`org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`

also `loginFormUrl` has become a constructor parameter.

See [LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html). The rename happens on [SEC-1160](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/1409) on 12.05.2009 07:37:11